# Excel cell format [$-10409]m-d-yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM

Tags: c#, excel, exceldatareader

I have a c# application where data is read from an MS excel file. The excel cell format is `[$-10409]m-d-yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM`

[image]

I am using **ExcelDataReader** from **NuGet** to read data from the excel file.

```
var file = new FileInfo(strFilePath);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(strFilePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            IExcelDataReader reader = null;
            if (file.Extension == ".xls")
            {
                reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);

            }
            else if (file.Extension == ".xlsx")
            {
                reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
            }

            ds = reader.AsDataSet();
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
        }
```

When I read data, the value is changed. e.g. `7-1-2016 11:05:00 AM` is converted to `42552.4618055556`.

Is there any way to get the correct value while reading?

Comment: Thanks @Scroog1. It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

The date you see as a double is the number of days since 1900-01-01. If you take `42552.46/365=116.58`.

Using this method to translate is not suggested as leap years do exist. You can reformat the cell by:

1. Highlight cells
2. Click format cells
3. Choose date
4. Choose date visualization format

Comment: The excel file (which is input for my application) is generated from some other application (SSIS). I can't reformat it.